# pymongo datetime TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pymongo

I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
import datetime

TODAY_DATE = datetime.date.today()
THREE_MONTH = datetime.timedelta(weeks=12)
FOUR_MONTH = datetime.timedelta(weeks=16)
START_DAY = TODAY_DATE - FOUR_MONTH
END_DAY = TODAY_DATE - THREE_MONTH 

x = agent_coll_obj.find({ "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime.datetime(START_DAY), 
                                             "$lt": datetime.datetime(END_DAY) }})
print x
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 212, in <module>
    program.runProgram()
  File "main.py", line 61, in runProgram
    report.RcreateReport()
  File "/Users/dwstein_old/Dropbox/hkpr_reports/report.py", line 105, in RcreateReport
    x = agent_coll_obj.find({ "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime.datetime(START_DAY), 
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I was trying to use this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366417/how-to-make-a-query-date-in-mongodb-using-pymongo) as a guide.  I'm trying to just use the whole date as opposed to having variables for the year, month, and day for each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [specify](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) year, month, day for datetime.datetime function.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
import datetime

TODAY_DATE = datetime.date.today()
THREE_MONTH = datetime.timedelta(weeks=12)
FOUR_MONTH = datetime.timedelta(weeks=16)
START_DAY = TODAY_DATE - FOUR_MONTH
END_DAY = TODAY_DATE - THREE_MONTH 

x = agent_coll_obj.find({ "created_at": {"$gte" : START_DAY, 
                                         "$lt": END_DAY }})
print x
```

you can use datetime.datetime like this:

```
In [2]: datetime.datetime?
Docstring:
datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])

The year, month and day arguments are required. tzinfo may be None, or an
instance of a tzinfo subclass. The remaining arguments may be ints or longs.
File:      /usr/local/opt/pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload  /datetime.so
Type:      type
```