# OperationFailure Unsupported projection option: endingDate

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to get the document whose endingDate is greater or equal to currentDateTime and also fetching entityID.

```
    {"_id":{"$oid":"5ecfba0b1191f2b87ee1ccd2"},
    "entityId":"5ecfb9d9d654557162afd861",
    "endingDate":{"$date":"2020-08-11T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

My query is:

```
cursor= list(db.collection.find({},{"entityId":1,
"endingDate":{"$gte":datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}}))
```

But it giving me error.

```
OperationFailure: Unsupported projection option: endingDate: { $gte: "2020-08-11T19:28:06.677643" }
```

**Edit 1:**
I tried this  query also

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
temp=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(temp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

cursor=list(db.TrendAnalysisSystem_jobdata.find({},
            {"entityId":1,"hashTags":1,"skillsRequired":1,
             "specialization":1,"endingDate":{"$gte":date_time_obj}}))
```

still getting the same error

Comment: This may help [How to make a query date in mongodb using pymongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366417/how-to-make-a-query-date-in-mongodb-using-pymongo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the find condition into the projection argument. Try:

```
  cursor= list(db.collection.find({"endingDate":        {"$gte":datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}},{"entityId":1,    }))
```